# Unable to run Normal SpringBoot application as it says "NoClassDefFoundError"!

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im running my Springboot application and facing the below problem because of the folder format,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication   at com.io.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:17) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Here is my main class,

```
/**
 *  created by KishorKumarRavi on 17-Mar-2018 at  12:58:40 PM
 */
package com.io.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

//Update:
The problem with the above is the folders are not structured properly. All the packages what you need to be added into the Application.java file which was created during the project setup.

Comment: As the stacktrace mentions there seems to be some classes missing, in this case the SpringApplication class. This automatically creates the following question.

How are you building your project? Did you make sure that all you dependencies are managed correctly?

Comment: It was because the project was not having proper folder format after which it worked perfectly..!

Comment: @KishorkumarR How did you solve it.same error is coming for my project also and i am using STS for running .

Comment: make sure your main class(Application.java by default) is under src.main.java.xxx.yyy.zzz.. and also add all your other packages under the same.!